# Return number of alphabetical substrings within input string

Tags: string, python-2.7, python-3.x, substring

I'm trying to generate code to return the number of substrings within an input that are in sequential alphabetical order. 
i.e. Input: 'abccbaabccba' 
Output: 2

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def cake(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range (len(x)+1):
            s = x[i:j+1]
            l = 0
            if s in alphabet:
                l += 1
    return l

print (cake('abccbaabccba'))
```

So far my code will only return 1. Based on tests I've done on it, it seems it just returns a 1 if there are letters in the input. Does anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the output `1` every time because your code resets the count to `l = 0` on *every* pass through the loop.

If you fix this, you will get the answer 96, because you are including a lot of redundant checks on empty strings (`'' in alphabet` returns `True`).

If you fix *that*, you will get 17, because your test string contains substrings of length 1 and 2, as well as 3+, that are also substrings of the alphabet.  So, your code needs to take into account the minimum substring length you would like to consider—which I assume is 3:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def cake(x, minLength=3):
    l = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(i+minLength, len(x)): # carefully specify both the start and end values of the loop that determines where your substring will end
            s = x[i:j]
            if s in alphabet:
                print(repr(s))  
                l += 1
    return l

print (cake('abccbaabccba'))
```